# What are the [scoring] and [scores] tags about?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-reorganization

I just noticed that we have [scoring](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scoring) tag -- what is it about? It does not have description. It's content is pretty chaotic: from [Good books/papers on credit scoring](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/55237/good-books-papers-on-credit-scoring) (my initial guess for what is it about), to [Scoring new observations after cross-validation](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/18832/scoring-new-observations-after-cross-validation), or [Cut Score Determination in IRT](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/134418/cut-score-determination-in-irt) ...

It probably needs some cleaning-up but it is hard to start as it is pretty ambiguous...

Comment: There is also [tag:scores]. I came across these tags before and find them very confusing.

Comment: @amoeba "scores" is almost like "numbers"...

Comment: If we can't figure out a reasonable use for it, we might add it to the [burninate list](http://meta.stats.stackexchange.com/q/3031/7290). There are too many garbage tags on the site now for optimal organization, IMO.

Comment: I would think procedures like [Kemeny-Young method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kemeny%E2%80%93Young_method) would be the focus of this topic. This appears to disagree with most of the other votes I have seen so far, which implies it would not have the highest score as dictated by the Kemeny Young method.

Comment: The answer of @amoeba can be accepted to close this thread now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Both [scoring](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scoring)×40 and [scores](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scores)×78 are ambiguous and should be eliminated. We have a variety of other more specific tags that could be used instead:

[z-score](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/z-score), [change-scores](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/change-scores), [scoring-rules](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scoring-rules), [propensity-scores](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/propensity-scores), [credit-scoring](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/credit-scoring), [fisher-scoring](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fisher-scoring)

(all of them have clear scope and wiki excerpts).

Apart from that,

- We do not need any tag for **PCA or FA scores.** This is too specific  (and worse, is field-dependent; many questions ask about PCA/FA "scores" without using "scores" terminology). Just use [pca](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pca) or [factor-analysis](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/factor-analysis).
- **Ratings.** For this we have a [rating](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rating) tag. Example: [Intelligence Squared Scoring and Winner Determination](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/94192)
- **Predictions**, as in [Scoring new observations after cross-validation](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/18832). I guess [prediction](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/prediction) would be appropriate.

======= edit 15 Nov 2017 =============

The [scores](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scores) is now empty. For most of them deletion was sufficient but there were a handful of each of the suggestions given above. I (@mdewey) voted to close a few too as unclear.

======= further edit 19 Nov 2017 ==========

The [scoring](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scoring) is now empty too

Comment: @mdewey Thanks a lot for taking care of this issue!