# What is the meaning and scope of our [data-generating-process] (synonym [dgp]) tag?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-deletion

We have a [data-generating-process](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/data-generating-process) tag with 20 Qs, no wiki excerpt, and a synonym [dgp](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dgp).

Wikipedia mentions at least three different interpretations of the term: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_generating_process

It seems to have a specific meaning in econometrics, from which the acronym DGP appears to be derived, see for example [here](http://www.rimini.unibo.it/fanelli/econometric_models2_2012.pdf) or [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/7836/in-regression-analysis-whats-the-difference-between-data-generation-process-and), or even more generally in the context of regression, [where the population regression function PRF is a feature of the DGP](http://fedc.wiwi.hu-berlin.de/xplore/tutorials/xegbohtmlnode5.html).

However, vaguer usage of the term, similar to the first definition give in Wikipedia ("the data-collection process") also seems to be used elsewhere, e.g. [here](https://www.coursera.org/learn/leadership-marketing/lecture/At3ej/the-data-generating-process).

In what sense is it supposed to be used on CrossValidated? I.e., what should be its usage guidelines?

Comment: I don't think that Wikipedia page is very good. OTOH, I'm not sure if we really need a `[dgp]` tag, either. I'll have to look at some & see how the tag helps categorize the information.

Comment: Seeing that there are only 20 Qs in this tag, I also doubt we really need it.

Comment: @amoeba I agree with that

Comment: @amoeba Wait, should both [dgp] and [data-generation-process] be eliminated? Or just the latter? EDIT: never mind, I forgot that dgp is a synonym of data-generation-process

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I looked into it and it seems that [data-generation-process](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/data-generation-process) is a pretty useless tag that should be eliminated. In most cases people seem to be using it instead of our well-established [random-generation](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/random-generation) tag, which only creates confusion.

With only 20 Qs, eliminating this tag is an easy task that can be done in around 3 sittings (see [When re-tagging old threads, how many should one do at once?](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4285)). You now have 2k rep and so are able to edit questions; if nobody protests here in a day or two, it would be great if you could do it.

**Update:** Done by @Chill2Macht, thanks!

Comment: I am willing to do this, no problem -- I hadn't checked this thread again recently, I'm sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @Chill2Macht Cool.

Comment: @Chill2Macht But please ping me here once you are done - I will make an update to this answer, so that everybody is informed.

Comment: Sorry about the delay, I just finished.

Comment: Great! I updated the answer.

Comment: By the way, @Chill2Macht, if you are interested in doing some tag work, I can point you to some ongoing or queued retagging projects. Just let me know :) There is much more work needed here than there are people willing to help.

Comment: That sounds interesting to me -- I don't know in advance if I would have time for all of them, but certainly it would be worth looking into

Comment: @Chill2Macht You can basically navigate our Meta and look for topics in [meta-tag:tag-reorganization]. Here is the latest issue that I posted yesterday: https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4774 -- this one is an easy job. There are other pending issues that require substantial work: e.g. https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4306, or https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3065, or https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4248. There are also tags to be removed: https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3031/ where some tags can be done manually.