# Sort out [hotelling] into [hotelling-t2]

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-reorganization

We have a [hotelling](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hotelling) tag with 24 Qs, no excerpt, and unclear scope. We also have a [hotelling-t2](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hotelling-t2) with only 8 Qs, but with an excerpt, and clear scope.

I suggest that we need to go through all [hotelling] threads and sort the ones about Hotelling T^2 distribution/test into [hotelling-t2], and remove the tag from everything else (e.g. questions about canonical correlations).

That's an easy job, but I still wanted to protocol it here.

Comment: Good stuff. Looking through, I think that's the appropriate action. (Edit: I've done a few at the top of the list; all were pretty obviously either -t2 or not -t2)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is done, `[hotelling]` is no more.